# Open default explorer Activity

Tags: android

Starting from Android 6 is available a default file explorer. You can open it in the storage settings using the explore button. I want to open it from app but I can't find an intent, any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
fileManagerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent fileManagerIntent = new Intent();
      fileManagerIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
      fileManagerIntent.setType("file/*");
      startActivity(fileManagerIntent);
   }
}
```

Comment: It's not the same thing, I can't open a file manually in this way

Answer (score 0):

I found the code used by settings app. It starts a new activity calling the method buildBrowseIntent() of VolumeInfo class. The VolumeInfo class use this code to build the intent:

```
public Intent buildBrowseIntent() {
        final Uri uri;
        if (type == VolumeInfo.TYPE_PUBLIC) {
            uri = DocumentsContract.buildRootUri(DOCUMENT_AUTHORITY, fsUuid);
        } else if (type == VolumeInfo.TYPE_EMULATED && isPrimary()) {
            uri = DocumentsContract.buildRootUri(DOCUMENT_AUTHORITY,
                    DOCUMENT_ROOT_PRIMARY_EMULATED);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        final Intent intent = new Intent(DocumentsContract.ACTION_BROWSE);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        intent.setData(uri);
        // note that docsui treats this as *force* show advanced. So sending
        // false permits advanced to be shown based on user preferences.
        intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_SHOW_ADVANCED, isPrimary());
        intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_FANCY_FEATURES, true);
        intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_SHOW_FILESIZE, true);
        return intent;
    }
```